# Sort column by value that contains hyphen and apply sorting after the hyphen

Tags: sql-server

I have a column with type (varchar) that contains a hyphen. The numbers after the hyphen represent a year. I need to sort by year first.

11-18
10-18
11-16
12-17
10-19

should be sorted like this:

11-16
12-17
10-18
11-18
10-19

Comment: Can the string be converted to a date datatype (which would then sort correctly)?

Comment: No, it can't be converted to date. There are some rows that may contain a letter at the end. I failed to mention that in the original post. John Cappelletti solution seems to work well.

Comment: You might want to filter out data not in the correct format anyways.  Something along the lines of "where my_col like '..-..' (i think period is single character wild card, right)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By right(SomeCol,2),SomeCol
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol
11-16
12-17
10-18
11-18
10-19
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE(CODE VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @T
       SELECT '11-18'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '10-18'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '11-16'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '12-17'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '10-19';
SELECT *
FROM @t
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(CODE, 4, 2), 
         SUBSTRING(CODE, 1, 2);
```

Comment: While this would work if my data were always in this format, I should have mentioned that there are times when the first group contains 3 numbers and there are also times when a letter is at the end. John C's solution seems to work best. Thanks.